# how to allow insecure content to be displayed on page

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-status-code-401, external-url

I am trying make AJAX request to external url and try to get Json data from that url. I am getting 401- Authorization error saying that its insecured content when try access the url. Here below is my code. Please advise

```
function check() {

    var ENV_URL = 'http://../BlueLight/api/BlueLights/getActiveBlueLight';   
    $('#trBlueLight').hide();
    $.getJSON(ENV_URL+"&callback=?", function (data) {
        if (data.expDate != null) {
            $('#trBlueLight').show();
        } else {
            $('#trBlueLight').hide();
        }
    });
    }
```

Comment: Request the content using your server instead.

Comment: either start the page with an unsecure protocoll (http:// instead of https://), you your server as proxy with apache mod_proxy, or as Kevin B send a request to the server. PHP or other Server Side Languages will be able to load unsecure content. But this could cost high traffic!

Comment: Can you let me know how to request content from our server to external url. any sample code will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

So the is to long for a comment.
I assume you create the following file **proxy_loader.php** and put into your webservers **root** directory (normaly httpdocs).
It must be accessible from **https://domain.tdl/proxy_loader.php**

the file should look like this:

```
<?PHP

// get the url provided by javascriot
$url= $_GET['url'];

// initialize CURL
$ch = curl_init();

// additional headers like session id etc.
$header = '';

// optional user & password
$userpass = 'user:password';

//$parameters for the request
// use parameter name as array key
// use parameter value as array value
$param = array();

// set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
//this enables the output into a variable
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// set optional header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
// set request method to GET
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
// optional http authenfication
// remove the // to enable
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $userpass);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $param);

// execute the request
// and save the response in $ret
$ret = curl_exec($ch);

// close the connection
curl_close($ch);

echo $ret;

// maybe you must use this:
// echo json_encode($ret);
?>
```

Now you could request a url through your server using a function like this:

```
function check() {

    var ENV_URL = 'http://../BlueLight/api/BlueLights/getActiveBlueLight';   

    $('#trBlueLight').hide();

    $.getJSON('/proxy_loader.php?url=' + ENV_URL, function (data) {
        if (data.expDate != null) {
            $('#trBlueLight').show();
        } else {
            $('#trBlueLight').hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can place code on both domains, XDM is quite easy to obtain, code samples [here](http://easyxdm.net/wp/)